# Unwanted string in while loop input to a file

Tags: c++, dictionary, while-loop, text-files

Currently, I'm trying to input a users choice into a text file. I have done this part, but for my while loop, I have an exit option as a string. It also prints "exit" into the file and I can't figure out a way to stop it from doing this. getName simply gets the users input and getNum does the same but with numbers. I've tried finding a solution to this, but every attempt I've made hasn't been succesful. I'd really appreciate any feedback, as I'm quite new to coding.

```
while (m.menu == "1")
{
    m.getName();

    writeFile << m.name;

    if (m.name == "exit")
    {
        break;
    }

    m.getNum();

    writeFile << m.number;

    if (m.number == "exit")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: place `writeFile << m.name;` after `if (m.name == "exit")`

Comment: If you don't want to do something with specific values, check them before doing that thing instead of afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Harry! I now understand why it wasn't working.